# const function declaration in haskell

Tags: haskell, function-declaration, haskell-prelude

I am confused about one particular example of the `const` function. So the type declaration `const :: a -> b->a` states that the function accepts two parameters of type `a` and `b` and returns a type `a`. For example:

```
const 5 3 => 5
const 1 2 => 1
```

This makes sense based on the declaration. However, I ran into this specific example:

```
const (1+) 5 3 => 4
```

This makes me question my understanding of the function declaration. I know this function only takes two parameters because I tried:

```
const 1 5 3
```

Now this reassures to me that it only takes 2 parameters. So how does this work? Is the `(1+)` not a parameter? If not, what is it?

```
const (1+) 5 3 => 4
```

Comment: Remember that `a` can be any type and the `b` gets ignored. A specific case could be `(a -> a -> a) -> b -> (a -> a -> a)`. The `b` gets ignored and returned is a function `a -> a -> a` waiting for two new inputs.

Comment: `(1+)` is a single parameter but it can also accept one parameter which means it's a function. `const` returns it and it, quite naturally accepst a parameter (the third one, `3` in your example)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I know this function only takes two parameters (…)

Every function in Haskell takes *one* parameter. Indeed, if you write:

```
 const 5  1
```

then this is short for:

```
(const 5) 1
```

The type signature `const :: a -> b -> a` is a more compact form of `const :: a -> (b -> a)`.

So `const 5` will create a function that ignores the parameter (here `1`) and returns the value that it was given `5`.

Now for `const (1+) 5 3` thus thus means that we wrote:

```
((const (1+)) 5) 3
```

`const (1+)` will thus construct a function that ignores the parameter, and returns `(1+)`, hence `const (1+) 5` is `(1+)`. We thus then calculate:

```
(1+) 3
```

which is `4`.